# Confidence interval of Pearson’s correlation seems too tight for low N

Tags: normal-distribution, correlation, confidence-interval

Say we have a matrix **M** where each column is a book, each row is a user, and cells are ratings - cells may be empty (not rated), or have values from 1 (didn’t like the book) to 5 (loved the book).

If I calculate a correlation coefficient ([Pearson’s r](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)) between 2 columns (books), then a low value (-1 is minimum) means, roughly speaking, that users who loved book A hated book B, and a high value (1 is maximum) means that users who loved book A also loved book B.

The problem is that if only a very small number of people (let’s represent this number as **N**) read a given pair of books, we shouldn’t take that correlation value too seriously. In order to weight high-N correlations higher and low-N correlations lower, I looked into confidence intervals.

The process for getting a confidence interval on a correlation value r, according to [OnlineStatBook](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/estimation/correlation_ci.html) is:

1. Convert r to z' (Fisher's z' transformation)
2. Compute a confidence interval in terms of z'
3. Convert the confidence interval back to r

Using the above instructions and formulae, we get results like the following (if you speak python, you can see the calculations at this [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19r1kk52jep9XelG_UiT5ehhK0l34ZBiw)):

*For an r of 0.999 and N=4 (very low number of readers who read both books), we get a lower bound 95% confidence interval of 0.95.*

It seems odd to me that with only 4 samples, we can be 95% confident that the correlation is at least 0.95 (extremely high), even when the initial **r** is so high.

For practical purposes, I can make tweaks to "punish" low Ns more, but I'm sure I'm missing something. I'd love to get a deeper understanding, so any links or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With so few samples you are losing normality.  I edited my previous response because I realized your data is not two categories but rather 5 different ratings.  One might do a linear regression of one variable vs the other.  Then shuffle the A values to all their permutations and keep computing the coefficient. Assuming the truth is no correlation or a coefficient of 0, you can then compute the p-value of your coefficient based on the data.